# How do i write the if - else if code properly

Tags: swift, if-statement

I'm trying to make an if - else if statement writing two comparison operators in the 'else if' line (Int type). maybe is the syntax wrong?

i've tried to remove the parentheses from 'boysAge >= 21' but same results

```
var boysAge = 21
var message = "The customer is "
if boysAge < 21 {
    message += "underage"
}
else if (boysAge >= 21) && <70 {
    message += "allowed"
}
print(message)
```

xcode says that '<' is not a prefix unary operator

Comment: You're forgetting people who are over 70.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code should work this way :

```
if boysAge < 21 {
    message += "underage"
}
else if boysAge < 70 {
    message += "allowed"
}
```

If `boysAge` is not strictly less than 21, then of course it's greater than or equal to `21`. So you don't need to check it again.

Another way would be :

```
if boysAge < 21 {
    message += "underage"
}
else if 21..<70 ~= boysAge {
    message += "allowed"
}
```

Using the `~=` operator.

---

This seems to me like a great place to use switch case :

```
switch boysAge {
case ...20:
    message += "underage"
case 21..<70 :
    message += "allowed"
default:
    break
}
```

And you coud adjust the ranges to your liking.

Answer (score 2):

```
var boysAge = 21
var message = "The customer is "
if boysAge < 21 {
message += "underage"
}
else if boysAge >= 21 && boysAge < 70 {
  message += "allowed"
}
print(message)
```

You're missing a space between `<` and `70` and you need to say what variable to check again, so `boysAge < 70`. Also the parentheses are unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

The condition `(boysAge >= 21) && <70` is not correct. `<` is a binary operator. That means it needs a left side and a right side. The correct way to write the condition is:

```
boysAge >= 21 && boysAge < 70
```

However, note that the `boysAge >= 21` part is not necessary because it is already covered in the previous branch.

```
var boysAge = 21
var message = "The customer is "
if boysAge < 21 {
    message += "underage"
}
else if boysAge < 70 {
    message += "allowed"
}
print(message)
```